# SQL - setting two different values in one line of SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL which does exactly as intended:

```
UPDATE Zones 
SET Zones.Zone = (SELECT Zone FROM Zones_New WHERE Zones_New.ZONENO = ZONES.ZONENO)
```

However, this updates table `Zones` and sets the field `Zone` to be what the `Zone` name is in table `Zones_New` and matches this by the `ZoneNo`.

At the same time I want to do exactly the same but also set the `Name` field to what the `Zone` name is in table `Zones_New`.

So basically I'm setting `Zone` & `Name` to be what the value `Zone` is from table `Zones_New`

I just can't figure out the SQL so I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: One slight caution about the answers that recommend `UPDATE ... FROM` - if there's the possibility that `Zones_New` may contain multiple rows for the same `ZONENO` value, the `UPDATE` will not warn you. If you're lucky, the two `SET` columns will at least be consistent with one of the rows, but I'm not even sure if that's guaranteed (and because it's not standard SQL, we can't even check a reference to see what is guaranteed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Zones
SET Zones.Zone = Zones_New.Zone,
    Zones.Name = Zones_New.Name
FROM Zones
INNER JOIN Zones_New ON Zones.ZONENO = Zones_New.ZONENO
```

Note if you want to purposely set nulls for non-matching rows, you can use a LEFT JOIN instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could just run the subquery twice like this:

```
UPDATE Zones 
 SET Zones.Zone = (SELECT Zone 
                   FROM Zones_New 
                   WHERE Zones_New.ZONENO = ZONES.ZONENO),
     Zones.Name = (SELECT Zone 
                   FROM Zones_New 
                   WHERE Zones_New.ZONENO = ZONES.ZONENO)
```

or you could do it in a join

```
UPDATE Zones 
 SET Zones.Zone = Zones_New.Zone
     Zones.Name = Zones_New.Zone
FROM Zones
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Zones_New 
    ON Zones_New.ZONENO = ZONES.ZONENO
```

Both of this queries will `null` the data if a corresponding record is not found in the `Zones_New` table.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be just...

```
UPDATE Zones 
SET Zones.Zone = (SELECT Zone FROM Zones_New WHERE Zones_New.ZONENO = ZONES.ZONENO),
    Zones.Name = (SELECT Zone FROM Zones_New WHERE Zones_New.ZONENO = ZONES.ZONENO)
```

A more complex could be something like...

```
UPDATE Z
SET Zones.Zone = ZN.Zone
FROM Zones Z
  LEFT JOIN Zones_New ZN
    ON Z.ZONENO = ZN.ZONENO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Zones
SET Zones.Zone = Zones_New.Zone,
    Zones.Name = Zones_New.Name
FROM Zones, Zones_New
WHERE Zones.ZONENO = Zones_New.ZONENO
```